# Reset Column and Row sizes to default

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am building a script (accessed through a custom menu item) that will also include some styling. Things like setting background colours, changing the width of columns, the heights of rows and inserting a lot of content.

Now I would like to implement a 'reset'-function: set **all** cells back to what a default, empty Google Sheet looks like, including all content. I found the `clear()` [function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#clear) in the documentation, but this only removes the content while keeping the width/height the same.

**The question:**
How can i reset a modified spreadsheet (content, width/height, styling) back to looking like a default Google Sheet spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, this plan should work:

1. add new sheet
2. define defaults: `getColumnWidth(columnPosition)` and `getRowHeight(rowPosition)`
3. delete new sheet
4. set defaults: `setColumnWidth(columnPosition, width)` and `setRowHeight(rowPosition, height)`

For more info look at [Class Sheet documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)

Comment: I was hoping there'd be a better functionality for this, but the lack of other responses seem to indicate no. I will take an existing cell from my current sheet in order to minimize weird operations, but since i got the idea from your answer, i'll mark it accepted :) Thanks

Answer (score 5):

There is now functionality for this.

Right-click on the column and select `Resize the column`.

Then set the width to 100px as is the default.

Comment: While this doesn't answer the question asked (scripted solution), it is what I came here looking for ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

I needed the same thing, so here's the code, based on [Max Makhrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5372400/max-makhrov)'s idea:

```
let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
let sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; // sheet you want to change
let tempSheet = ss.insertSheet((new Date()).toLocaleTimeString()); // temp sheet

sheet.setColumnWidths(1, sheet.getMaxColumns(), tempSheet.getColumnWidth(1));
sheet.setRowHeights(1, sheet.getMaxRows(), tempSheet.getRowHeight(1));
ss.deleteSheet(testSheet);
```